# How can I change the ordering of a std::map to be reversed?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Does anyone know that is there a way that I can change the map order from less to kind of "more"?

For example:

There is a `map<string, int>` called `test`. I insert some entries to it:

```
test["b"] = 1;
test["a"] = 3;
test["c"] = 2;
```

Inside the map, the order will be `(a, 3)(b, 1)(c, 2)`.

I want it to be `(c, 2)(b, 1)(a, 3)`.

How can I do that in a easy way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using `std::greater` as your key instead of `std::less`.

e.g.

```
std::map< std::string, int, std::greater<std::string> > my_map;
```

See [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That's what I exactly need. I saw it once before. I recalled the usage now. Appreciate. @GManNickG is welcomed as well :)

Comment: @XinLi Welcome to SO. Please have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see how the site works and to understand upvoting and accepting answers. Have a good time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing map, and you just want to loop over the elements of a map in reverse, use a reverse iterator:

```
// This loop will print (c, 2)(b, 1)(a, 3)

for(map< string, int >::reverse_iterator i = test.rbegin(); i != test.rend(); ++i)
{
    cout << '(' << i->first << ',' << i->second << ')';
}
```

Comment: Hi @beerboy, your gave me another way to think about my coding. Thank you.